# Set editingAccessoryType to a UISwitch

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

```
typedef enum : NSInteger {
   UITableViewCellAccessoryNone,
   UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator,
   UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton,
   UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark,
   UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailButton
} UITableViewCellAccessoryType;
```

I don't see a switch style. What is the best method to display the switch while still updating the cell correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't use `accessoryType` or `editingAccessoryType` for this. Use `accessoryView` or `editingAccessoryView`.

```
UISwitch *switch = ... // create and setup the switch
cell.editingAccessoryView = switch;
```